# Cannot acces container behind traefik inside a podman's pod

Tags: network-programming, traefik, podman

After reading the [docs](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/basic_networking.md), I understand that a `podman pod` makes the communication between containers easy since they can find each other via `localhost`. It can be summarized as in the picture below:

[image: Example from https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/images/2022/07/9-pods-drawing.webp]

I created a pod in podman with the command to share the network namespace except the port forwarding:

`podman pod create --name test_pod --share cgroup,ipc,uts`

and I've put pgadmin and traefik inside this pod by doing:

```
podman run -d \
  --name pgadmin \
  --pod=test_pod \
  --label "traefik.enable=true" \
  dpage/pgadmin4:7.8

podman run -d \
  --name traefik \
  --pod=test_pod \
  --volume=./traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml \
  --volume=./routers/:/etc/traefik/routers/ \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 8081:80 \
  -p 8433:433 \
  traefik:v2.10.5
```

The `traefik.yml` looks like this:

```
...
entrypoints:
  http:
    address: :80
  https:
    address: :433
  pgadmin:
    address: :3744

providers:
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/routers
```

and my router is simply:

```
http:
  routers:
    pgadmin:
      entryPoints:
        - pgadmin
      service: pgadmin
      rule: "Host(`pgadmin.com`)"

  services:
    pgadmin:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://localhost:80
```

In my host's machine `/etc/hosts` I have the entries of "traefik.com" and "pgadmin.com" mapped to the ocal IP Address of the host.

However, I cannot access pgadmin in any way. The `netstat` command inside pgadmin shows me that it is listening at port 80 and traefik has the routing correctly recognized. Why can I not access pgadmin in any way from the host?